# disable `functools.lru_cache` from inside function

Tags: python, python-decorators, functools

I want to have a function that can use `functools.lru_cache`, but not by default. I am looking for a way to use a function parameter that can be used to disable the `lru_cache`. Currently, I have a two versions of the function, one with `lru_cache` and one without. Then I have another function that wraps these with a parameter that can be used to control which function is used

```
def _no_cache(foo):
    print('_no_cache')
    return 1


@lru_cache()
def _with_cache(foo):
    print('_with_cache')
    return 0


def cache(foo, use_cache=False):
    if use_cache:
        return _with_cache(foo)
    return _no_cache(foo)
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: You can't handle that from *inside* the function - if it's a cache hit, the function never even gets invoked.

Comment: all you can invent here properly - is just a Factory function which will return cached or uncached function object (depending on parameter), not the a function result

Comment: RomanPerekhest why would I want to return the function object instead of the function results?

Comment: @TheStrangeQuark, there are various scenarios of generating objects. No one compels you to extend a "home" code, it's up to you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't disable the cache from inside the decorated function. However, you can simplify your code a bit by accessing the function directly via the `__wrapped__` attribute.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache):

> The original underlying function is accessible through the `__wrapped__`
>   attribute. This is useful for introspection, for bypassing the cache,
>   or for rewrapping the function with a different cache.

Demo:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def f(arg):
    print(f"called with {arg}")
    return arg    

def call(arg, use_cache=False):
    if use_cache:
        return f(arg)
    return f.__wrapped__(arg)

call(1)
call(1, True)
call(2, True)
call(1, True)
```

Output:

```
called with 1
called with 1
called with 2
```

Answer (score 3):

For inspection, you can use `cache_info()` method of wrapped function:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def my_function(foo):
    return foo * 2

def cache(foo, use_cache=False):
    if use_cache is False:
        return my_function.__wrapped__(foo)
    return my_function(foo)

print(cache(10, use_cache=True))    # cache miss
print(cache(10, use_cache=True))    # cache hit
print(cache(10, use_cache=False))   # bypass
print(cache(20, use_cache=False))   # bypass

print(my_function.cache_info())     # cache size=1, hit=1, miss=1
```

Prints:

```
20
20
20
40
CacheInfo(hits=1, misses=1, maxsize=128, currsize=1)
```